# azure function binding datetime yesterday

Tags: python, azure, datetime, binding, azure-functions

I have an Azure function (in Python), and in my `function.json` file I have an output blob binding like the following:

```
{
  "type": "blob",
  "name": "outputBlob",
  "path": "myblob/test_{datetime:yyyyMMdd}.txt",
  "connection": "my_connection_str",
  "direction": "out"
}
```

This works fine, but it only considers the date when the function is executed. What if I want to get, or write a file with yesterday's date, or with last month's?

Can I perform functions on that expression?

Comment: In such case, seek date value from using raw_input.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean, @Ajay2588. Could you elaborate?

Comment: any updates here?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not with the datetime expression. Your best bet would likely be to have some information you could bind to coming from your input.

In other languages, you have finer control (including late binding support allowing you to control every aspect of how the binding behaves), but that isn't available in Python.

Comment: Thank you Fabio. Well, that's quite disappointing. Are there any workarounds? For instance, can I write the binding code in C# and call it from python?